# History of monogamy

Tags: cultural-history, social-history

Is monogamy a feature of advanced cultures that emphasize a person’s individuality? I mean cultures that treat someone as person and not as an anonymous part of something else, e.g. nature or a tribe.

Comment: Are you asking if monogamy only appears in "advanced cultures that emphasize a person’s individuality"?

Comment: What research have you done?  From memory, I the the concept of the individual is a modern concept, so the question is a tautology.

Comment: Monogamy exists elsewhere in the animal world. See e.g. geese. There's nothing specifically human about it.

Comment: I mean that man in the effort to complete his ego is devoted erotic only to one person and not to many other.

Comment: what are you talking about...  are people monogamous now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standards for inter-gender relations appear to be a deep cultural thing. As such, it tends to go hand-in-hand with language family, which means the root of the differences probably go back to a time when pretty much *everyone* was operating in the Mesolithic ("Stone Age")

Indo-European cultures tend to a strict one-to-one marriage, with offspring from pairings outside that system not being considered legitimate.

Afro-asiatic cultures tend to a one (male) to many marriage system, where male offspring are accorded status by birth order (regardless of mother).

Chinese cultures have a middle-ground between these two poles, where a man can have more than one wife, but the senior wife and her offspring have elevated status.

Tibetian culture traditionally went instead toward Polyandry (or in rare cases involving no male heirs polygamy), with all male children having equal status.

Mongolian culture had strict binary marriage, like the Indo-Europeans, but all male children got close to equal status, with the *youngest* being slightly advantaged, getting undividable things like the father's title and actual tent location. The Ancient Mongolians would probably claim they were indeed more "advanced" than their Chinese neighbors, but I suspect the Chinese would strongly disagree. In writing.

I'd caution anyone against picking out a cultural feature that happened to be used by the winners of the Age of Imperialism and trying to find a reason why that one is somehow better. This isn't anything more than [Survivorship Bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias).

Comment: I have a few doubts about that reasoning when it went from cultural (agreed) to language (?) Southern and Eastern Indo-European branches seem nonconforming to this theory? Anatolian, Persian, Tocharian? Anyway, a few more sources would be welcome…

Comment: @LangLangC - Cultures are messy, so its obviously not a hard-and immutable law of nature. Just a tendency. Languages and marriage customs are simply two components of a culture that a people don't give up easily. For example, technically Chinese and Tibetian are part of a single Sino-Tibetian language family. So if you want to be hyper-technical about it, the whole thing falls down there. But that doesn't change the fact that the two things tend to go together.

Comment: Also in many societies norms were different for the elites and everyone else.

Comment: This answer is likely wrong IMO. Even in cultures where it's nominally allowed for men to have multiple wives, few men actually have more than one. I'd be willing to bet that one observes a similar outcome for wives in cultures that (if only nominally) allow for women to have multiple husbands. And from an anatomical standpoint we're [a far cry from chimps](https://medium.com/@tgof137/chimps-bonobos-and-the-evidence-that-humans-are-naturally-polygamous-a895b5b1abce).

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy - I'm missing where that (quite factual) statement intersects the text of this answer.

Comment: @T.E.D.: What rubs me in a wrong way is that your answer makes it sound like there are culture groups out there that are polygamous or polyandrous, whereas in reality, even those cultures that are nominally one or the other are actually monogamous in practice. And to the best of my knowledge the anatomical and ethological evidence suggest that we've most (not all) of the characteristics of a monogamous species.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy - Obviously not *everyone* can be in that situation. With a roughly 50/50 split of genders, that's just a basic mathematical fact.

Comment: @T.E.D.: There's more to it than basic stats. Take Muslim cultures, for instance. Leaving aside that some Muslim countries banned or restricted the practice, it is nominally polygamous. In practice, even when it is legal, the only polygamous households around are those of the upper strata of society. Muslim women don't put up with the idea of sharing a man any more than women in monogamous societies. (To be clear, that's also because feminism took hold; but even before it did, one would need to be able to afford having more than one wife, which was and still is an issue.)